# Communicating between a Lightroom plugin and an iOS app over a LAN

Tags: ios, sockets, plugins, io, lightroom

I've asked this on Adobe's LR SDK forum, thought I'd ask here as well.

I want to create a plugin for Lightroom 6+ that allows two-way communication to take place between a LR plugin and an iOS app. The iOS device would be on the same local network.

What is the best method of accomplishing this? I was thinking about using LRSocket, this is the most direct method? I assume with this method the iOS app would need to act as the server and the LR plugin would be the connecting client? But, all the documentation and examples I’ve found, regarding general LRSocket usage, imply that localhost is used. This would make direct communication with an iOS device over WiFi impossible if it can only use localhost?

Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I've just started out trying to do the same thing, albeit with an Android app, and run into the same (apparently insurmountable) issue that LrSocket.Bind only seems to be able to bind to the localhost interface.

The only way I can think to get around this is to have an intermediary port forwarder on the LR host OS that forwards traffic between localhost:port and ethernet/wifi:port

You could use ssh on a mac, I guess, and there are port-forwarding applications for Windows (ssh is allegedly coming soon). PassPort (an old application from the XP era still seems to work).

It's a bit....messy, though.

Another option would be to use LrHttp.get (and/or .post), but that's going to have to poll for information, and may be a bit laggy for some requirements.

Comment: Thanks for you respons, I ended up making a small server app to function as the go-between for the plugin and the mobile app.